# How to retrieve all elements of an array, on which a specific does not exist?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider the following data:

```
{
  "foo": "foo"
  "baz": [
    "D": 77
  ]
}
{
  "foo": "bar"
  "baz": [
    {
      "A": 5,
      "B": 15
    },
    {
      "A": 13,
      "B": 34,
      "C": 68,
    },
    {
      "A": 192,
      "B": 168,
      "C": 1,
      "D": 27
    }
  ]
},
{
  "foo": "baz"
  "baz": [
    {
      "A": 5,
      "B": 10
      "C": 15
    },
    {
      "A": 13,
      "D": 37,
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried finding all and only projecting the result, but due to the nature of `$elemMatch` this only returns the first element without the field `D`.

```
db.collection.find({}, {"baz": {$elemMatch: {"D": {$exists: false}}}})
```

How could I retrieve all documents, which have at least one element in `baz`, which has no field `D` and project it, so only the entries without the field `D` are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$anyElemetTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) for your filtering criteria and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to remove those `baz` elements that contain `D`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $anyElementTrue: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$baz",
                        in: { $eq: [ "$$this.D", undefined ]  }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            baz: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$baz",
                    cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.D", undefined ]  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SxCe0LHU8q5)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to achieve my goal:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$baz"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "baz.D": {$exists: false}
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      foo: "$foo", 
      baz: {$push: "$baz"}
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do this as:

    db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          foo: 1,
          baz: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$baz",
              as: "item",
              cond: {
                $lt: [
                  "$$item.D",
                  null
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
{
    $match: {
      baz: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  }
    ])
```